# Why a custom CSP dll isn't accepted by aplication like Adobe Reader or Word if it has dependencies to another custom dll?

Tags: cryptography

I have developed a custom Cryptographic Service Provider that has two parties:

- an c++ dll that implements the CryptoSPI functions (CPAquireContext, ...);
- an c# dll that makes get and post http requests, because the signature is performed in cloud by a signature web service.

To use the c# dll from c++ dll i have made a c++/cli wrapper. From a custom c++ console testing program all goes fine but if i want to use it from Adobe Reader it crashes with fallowing error message "Provider dll failed to initialize correctly". The problem is that my CSP isn't called (I have checked with log messages).I have tried also implicit linking (from visual studio) and explicit linking but it doesn't work.

The problem is linkage because if i remove the linkage to c++/cli wrapper, my CSP is called and Adobe Reader rrecognize it.

So, why Adobe Reader crashes if my custom CSP has dependencies to another custom dll?

Comment: This looks like a question better asked on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @nobody ok, thanks!